# Fade out circle layer from center jQuery/GSOP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, gsap

I have created two layer div, one with background image and another with a black layer which is fading out, seems to okay but the requirement is a bit different, the fade out layer should start from center (circle), as per the example below:

[image: example fade out from center position]

This is what I have created, [JSfiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/1uzj2v5L/)

Can anybody please suggest how to get achieve that circle type centered fadeout, instead that the one which I have created? I have used greensock in my project.

Please suggest

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var videoFade = $(".fade-layer");
  TweenMax.to(videoFade, 14, { x:0 , opacity:0 , ease:Power1.easeInOut ,repeat:-1  });
});
```

```css
.layer-one{
  background:url(https://i.imgsafe.org/90203acca5.jpg); 
  background-size:cover; 
  background-position:center; 
  position:absolute; 
  left:0; 
  top:0; 
  width:100%; 
  height:100%; 
  z-index:1;
}
.fade-layer{
  background:rgba(0,0,0,1); 
  position:absolute; 
  left:0; 
  top:0; 
  width:100%; 
  height:100%; 
  z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.1/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<div class="layer-one"></div>
<div class="fade-layer"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you could use a single element for the background, a pseudo element for the black overlay, a `radial-gradient()` to create the overlay circle, and a CSS animation to fade the overlay out.

Here's a demo.

```css
div, div:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
}
div {
  background: url(https://i.imgsafe.org/90203acca5.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(0,0,0,0.8) 0%, black 100%);
  animation: fadeOut 10s forwards;
}
@keyframes fadeOut {
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: very close to what I was looking for, I have never thought about handling using CSS, but nice idea, thanks!

Comment: @SanjeevK you're welcome. Do you want to tell me what it is that won't work and I can try and help out, or do you not want to go this route? From reading your post, seems like this would work, so I'd be interested in why you say it's close but won't work.

Comment: I would rather go the way you suggested in the answer, just wondering if it can be more smooth (centered glow effect), however I am satisfied with the answer so far :)

Comment: @SanjeevK cool thanks for giving me your feedback. Oh and thanks for accepting the answer! What's a "centered flow effect" - can you link me to an example or description?

Comment: don't have exact example ready for now, and I mean centered glow effect, typos in last comment

Comment: @SanjeevK k, if you can show me an example, I'll see what I can do. It might just be a matter of changing the `radial-gradient` by introducing more breakpoints. I'm just doing a simple gradient, but you can change it to do all kinds of stuff. There are also css gradient generators online you can use to play around with it and try different things. http://www.cssmatic.com/gradient-generator

Comment: Yes, I have been playing around with the radial-gradient and I think now I can achieve as per my requirement, thanks a ton for you attention on this and thanks for sharing link :)

Answer (score 2):

I've not really worked with `GASP` but I was able to create a quick demo what you have to do with `box-shadow`. You can achieve what you are trying to do with that. Check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1uzj2v5L/4/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var videoFade = $(".fade-layer");
    TweenMax.to(videoFade, 5, { x:0 , opacity:0.5 , ease:Power1.easeInOut ,repeat:-1,
    boxShadow:"0px 0px 0px 0px rgb(0,0,0) inset;"});

  });
```

Comment: very nice attempt and good suggestion on this, I think the way you have added the box-shadow, border-radius can also be used to make it more better. I will give a try now to see how it goes.

Comment: I tried with border-radius but unfortunately no luck, I think I will have to find out a different approach.